# AmCharts 4 Force Directed Chart - Select Bubble by Parent -> Child Location

Tags: javascript, amcharts4

Using the demo chart available from the AmCharts website ([here](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/force-directed-network/)), if I know the parent `Phoebe`, and the child `David`, how can I programmatically get the `David` bubble?

My goal is to alter the fill of the bubble, which I can do in an event handler. I just am uncertain of how to select the element I want programmatically, given what I have to work with.

Edit: I realize that I can just traverse `graph.data` and modify the `color` attribute, but I can't call `graph.invalidateRawData()` as that doesn't pick up the coloring change (makes sense). I really would rather not have to force a complete graph redraw!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to get a desired node would be to set id data field (it can be the same as your name field) and use `series.getDataItemById` method to retrieve the data item.

```
function changeColor(){
let dataItem = networkSeries.getDataItemById(networkSeries.dataItems, "Fifth");
dataItem.node.circle.fill = am4core.color("#00ff00");

// change color of all children
dataItem.children.each(function(child){
    child.node.circle.fill = am4core.color("#00ffff");
})
}
```

Here is a demo:
https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/mZMYKx

The demo also illustrates how access and change color of all children of the data item.

Comment: It appears that the getDataItemById method was not yet documented, we will fix that in next release.

Comment: @geudrik Also, if somehow there are multiple Davids (say it's not the `id`, just some extra data for display), and you need to check its parent, you can use the [`ForceDirectedSeriesDataItem.parent` property](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/forcedirectedseriesdataitem/#parent_property). Please note both `parent` and `children` are still dealing with `ForceDirectedSeriesDataItem`s, not nodes. You can also use [an adapter](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/adapters/) instead of an event to return a custom color if the target circle's data matches up (whether Phoebe or David).